# Read each individual word in string per 'if'

Tags: java, string, if-statement

Is there a way to make Java read each individual word per 'if' in string?
I will try my best to explain this...

```
public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String sentence = "testing1 testing2 testing3 testing4"

        //Scan first word \/ 
        if(sentence.equals("testing1"){
            //scan second word \/
            if(sentence.equals("testing2"){
                //scan third word \/
                if(sentence.equals("testing3"){
                    System.out.println("Works good!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you can help me I would really appreciate it.

Comment: i don't understand your question, can you elaborate more on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, you may try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String sentence = "testing1 testing2 testing3 testing4";
    String[] arrayOfWords = sentence.split(" "); // split the sentence according to the spaces
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      //Scan first word
      System.out.println("Insert First Word");
      if(arrayOfWords[0].equals(in.next())){
            System.out.println("Insert Second Word");
            if(arrayOfWords[1].equals(in.next())){ 
               System.out.println("Insert Third Word");
               if(arrayOfWords[2].equals(in.next())){
                     System.out.println("Works good!");
               }
            }
        }
}
```

for example:

```
Insert First Word
testing1
Insert Second Word
testing2
Insert Third Word
testing3
Works good!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Scanner.next() like below:

```
String sentence = "testing1 testing2 testing3 testing4";
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(sentence)) {
    if (sc.next().equals("testing1")) {
        if (sc.next().equals("testing2")) {
            if (sc.next().equals("testing3")) {
                if (sc.next().equals("testing4")) {
                    System.out.println("Works good!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: May also think about using ["The try-with-resources Statement"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: @KeionBeats glad to help. You can also use one if statement like: if (sc.next().equals("testing1") && sc.next().equals("testing2") && sc.next().equals("testing3") && sc.next().equals("testing4"))

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] array = sentence.split(" ");

//Scan first word \/ 
if(array[0].equals("testing1"){
    //scan second word \/
    if(array[1].equals("testing2"){
        //scan third word \/
        if(array[2].equals("testing3"){
            System.out.println("Works good!")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of adding unnecessary code, consider writing an explanation for your answer and edit that in.